# SQL Server Mapping a user to a login and adding roles programmatically

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

In my SQL Server 2005 server I create databases and logins using Management Studio. My application requires that I give a newly created user read and write permissions to another database.

To do this I right-click the newly created login, select properties and go to User Mapping. I put a check beside the database to map this login to the db and select db_datareader and db_datawriter as the roles to map.

Can this be done programmatically? I've read about using Alter User and sp_change_users_login but I'm having problems getting these to work, since sp_change_users_login has been deprecated so I'd prefer to use Alter User.

Please note my understanding of SQL Server database users/logins/roles is basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logins are for the server instance.  Users are at the database level.  Roles are generally found at the database level but there are some fixed roles like sysadmin at the server instance level.

Go [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) for the grammar to create a user on a database.
Go [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750(SQL.90).aspx) for the syntax for adding that user to a database role.

You are likely going to execute something like the following to accomplish all of this.

```
Create Login temp1 with Password = '123!@#$FAF', Default_Database = test
GO
use test;
Create User user_blah1 from Login  temp1
GO
use test;
Exec sp_addrolemember  @rolename =  'db_datareader',
     @membername =  'user_blah1'
```